# The phrase "do no longer X"

Tags: meaning, idiomatic-language

> These old pictures do no longer calm my troubled mind.

> These old pictures no longer calm my troubled mind.

Is the addition of "do" idiomatic and is the meaning roughly the same? I feel it only adds a little bit of drama, but I am not sure if there's any significant change in meaning.

Comment: Is this a quotation, or did you write it?

Comment: I wrote it because I could not find an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addition of **do** is not idiomatic here.

I think you're thinking of the [**emphatic do**](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590), but the emphatic do can only be used for positive, affirmative sentences, and your example is a negative sentence.

For example, the following exchange is how the emphatic do is used:

> "These books don't give you any peace, do they?"
> "These books *do* give me peace."

You might also be thinking of the use of *do* as a main verb with "no X" as a noun phrase, like

> These medicines do no harm.

or a poetic rephrasing, like

> No longer do these old pictures calm my troubled mind.